# ERRO ao recuperar dados de um formulário através do $_POST[] em PHP

Tags: php, post, upload

Criei um formulário simples:

```
<form  action="php/cadastro.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Autor:</legend>
        <input type="text" name="autor" placeholder="Informe seu nome" required="required">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Título:</legend>
        <input type="text" name="titulo" placeholder="Informe um título para o post" required="required">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Descrição:</legend>
        <p>
            <textarea name="materia" placeholder="Digite o poste aqui..." required="required"></textarea>
        </p>
    </fieldset>     
    <fieldset>     
        <legend>Imagem:</legend>
        <input type="file" name="foto" required="required">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Postar" class="botao">
        <input type="submit" value="Cancelar" class="botao">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

No entanto, na hora de recuperar os dados para meu script apresenta o erro:

> Undefined index: foto in C:\wamp\www\comicnews\php\cadastro.php on line 6

Saída do `var_dump`:

```
array (size=3)
  'autor' => string 'Ademir Santos' (length=13)
  'titulo' => string 'Deadpool o maior heroi da terra' (length=31)
  'materia' => string 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer tortor justo, elementum vel tincidunt vitae, ullamcorper sed dolor. Etiam leo sapien, faucibus sit amet porttitor non, fermentum vitae mi. Curabitur ac velit ut ante bibendum consequat a et sem. Quisque pellentesque libero lacus, sed finibus purus iaculis vel.' (length=325)
```

Noto que não está encontrando o índice "foto" no array `$_POST['foto']`, a questão é por quê? Como resolver?

Eis o script PHP:

```
<?php

include_once  'conexao.php';

$autor=$_POST['autor'];
$imagem= $_POST['foto'];
$titulo=$_POST['titulo'];
$materia= $_POST['materia'];


var_dump($_POST);   

//insere no BD os dados da matéria e do autor, assim também como o caminho da imagem que ele deseja publicas
$query= "insert into noticia(titulo, descricao, img, autor) values ('{$titulo}','{$materia}','wamp/www/comicsnews/imagens/.{$imagem}','{$autor}')";

//Executa a query e mostra o resultado
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

if($resultado){

    echo "sucesso";

}else{

    echo "<br>Não salvou". mysqli_error($conexao);
}
```

desde já agradeço que puder ajudar.

Comment: coloque também a abertura da sua tag `<form>`, provavelmente você esta esquecendo o `enctype`.

Comment: Amigo...a imagem vc vai acessar pela $FILES

Comment: valeu, Israel isso mesmo acessa pelo $_FILES, não sabia disso, valeu Rafael, mas acontece que estava lá só que o crtlC ctrlV não pegou, mas de qualquer forma consegui resolver o problema e era por que precisa acessar com o $FILES mesmo, agradecido.

Comment: resolvido, valeu pela ajuda! os arquivos devem ser acessados pelo $_FILE[].

Answer (score 1):

Para enviar arquivos de imagens é necessário alterar o FORM:

```
<!-- O tipo de encoding de dados, enctype, DEVE ser especificado abaixo --> 
<form  enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="__URL__" method="POST">

        Enviar esse arquivo: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar arquivo" /> </form>
```

Observe que o form precisa ter o enctype `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

No lado do PHP você acessa da seguinte forma: `$_FILES[]`

Maiores esclarecimentos acesse o seguinte: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Valeu, não sabia que precisava usar o $_FILES[], achava que era pelo $_POST[] mesmo, era esse o erro, todas as outras modificações eu já tinha feito, só que estava tentando acessar com o $_POST[].

Comment: agradeço muito, obrigado.

Comment: ok.depois marca como respondida.